# ParseUI ... does not contain bitcode

Tags: ios, swift3, bitcode, parseui

Once I seem to have got rid of all the syntax errors, while converting my project to Swift 3.0.

I now hit this one:

```
    ld: '/Users/......./ParseUI.framework/ParseUI(PFLogInViewController.o)' does not contain bitcode. 
You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE),
 obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this
 target. for architecture arm64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 
(use -v to see invocation)
```

After trying a few option change in Xcode which did not have any effect, I don't see any clear solution to solve this issue.
Anyone has a simple and clear answer to that?

Answer (score -1):

[image]

In XCode, Select your project in Explorer > Select your Target> Make "Enable Bitcode" to No. And recompile your code.

If you enable bitcode in your target, then all the pods need to have enabled bitcode. But in your case Alamofire looks to be not bitcode enabled. So as long as it is so, you can't go ahead with "Enable Bitcode" option as Yes for your code.

Comment: I had tried this with not success. Plus I was not using Alamofire neither was I using pods(at the time). But I finally got rid of the issue by installing Parse through cocoa pods. I don't exactly know why, but the bug is now gone.